# Edit a figure from external function

Tags: matplotlib

I'm trying to edit a figure that was obtained using an external function.

For example, "nolds.lyap_r" function creates a figure. Let's say I want to add a title to it after it was plotted. How can I do it?

```
import nolds
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nolds.lyap_r(y, debug_plot=True)
```

I guess I need to use plt.gca() or plt.gcf() but it didn't work for me:

```
ax=plt.gca()
ax.set_title("ABC")
```

Comment: Have you tried `plt.title("Your title")`

Comment: ```plt.title('title')
      plt.show()
```

Comment: It creates a new figure with a title, instead of adding a title to the existing plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`pyplot.draw()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.draw.html) is there to update the existing figure:

```
plt.title('A good title')
plt.draw()
```

Comment: Thanks!
I actually found a simple solution:
putting plt.title('A good title') *BEFORE* the plotting instead of *AFTER* it